# Is it possible to override a web page's font-settings in Google Chrome for Windows

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Is it possible to tell Google Chrome for Windows "if the website has specified any serifed font, use {my own choice of serifed font} no matter what face the website has specified, and if the website has specified a sans-serifed font, use {my own choice of sans-serifed font} no matter what face the website has specified"?

I would like to choose the font faces that I find easiest to read. Is that possible in Chrome?